# Filter multi-dimensional array using key

Tags: php, arrays, object, filter

I need help from the PHP experts there. I want to do some filters in this result. I want to filter it using the key `custom_search_emp_id_11`. hope there's a shorter/one liner code/function to do filters? thank you in advance for the answers!

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [custom_search_emp_id_11] => flag_emp_id_11
            [custom_search] => flag_emp_id_11
            [eti_id] => 1
            [time] => 1:00
            [emp_id] => 11
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [custom_search_emp_id_22] => flag_emp_id_22
            [custom_search] => flag_emp_id_22
            [eti_id] => 4
            [time] => 1:00
            [emp_id] => 22
        )
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [custom_search_emp_id_33] => flag_emp_id_33
            [custom_search] => flag_emp_id_33
            [eti_id] => 5
            [time] => 1:00
            [emp_id] => 33
        )
    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [custom_search_emp_id_11] => flag_emp_id_11
            [custom_search] => flag_emp_id_11
            [eti_id] => 1
            [time] => 1:00
            [emp_id] => 11
        )
)
```

and the output will be :

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [custom_search_emp_id_11] => flag_emp_id_11
            [custom_search] => flag_emp_id_11
            [eti_id] => 1
            [time] => 1:00
            [emp_id] => 11
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [custom_search_emp_id_11] => flag_emp_id_11
            [custom_search] => flag_emp_id_11
            [eti_id] => 2
            [time] => 1:00
            [emp_id] => 11
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) with a function that checks for the existence of the `custom_search_emp_id_11` key in the objects:

```
$filtered_array = array_filter($array, function ($v) { return isset($v->custom_search_emp_id_11); });
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Z1sWK)

Comment: i dunno why my post have marked negative? can you click the arrow up? thanks!

Comment: @claire it was probably downvoted because you didn't make any attempt to solve the problem yourself.